# Simple date format giving the same date for two different strings

Tags: android, simpledateformat

I have written a small method to return a date object when given a string.  The method is as shown below:

```
public Date getDateObjectFromString(String dateAsString)
{
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
    Date tempDate = null;

    try
    {
        tempDate = sdf.parse(dateAsString);
    }
    catch(ParseException pe)
    {
        //do some error reporting here
    }
    return tempDate;
}
```

Everything is working ok, but I've run into something that I'd like to clarify.  When I pass two different strings to this method it is returning the same date when reading the value in the debugger.  The two strings I am passing are:

```
2011-07-21T19:44:00.000-0400

2011-07-21T19:44:00.000-04:00
```

As you can see these two strings are nearly identical, and when I look at the variable output for these newly created dates in the debugger, it shows the exact same date/time for either string.  So, does the colon in the second string (at 04:00) make any difference if the debugger is showing the same date?  Should I worry or can I proceed without any weird bugs popping up later on?

Comment: can you not normalize all your strings before passing them in? this might be the best way anyway

Comment: @citizen conn - yes...but I was just wondering what was the difference, if any.  Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android docs for [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) mention that they use RFC 822 timezones.  When I went to the JavaDocs for SimpleDateFormat, which is what Android is attempting to mimic with this class, I see [this note](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#timezone) about RFC 822 timezones:

> RFC 822 time zone: For formatting, the RFC 822 4-digit time zone
>   format is used:
>
> ```
>  RFC822TimeZone:
>          Sign TwoDigitHours Minutes
>  TwoDigitHours:
>          Digit Digit
> ```
>
> TwoDigitHours must be between 00 and 23. Other definitions are as for
>   general time zones. For parsing, **general time zones are also
>   accepted**.

And here is the note for **general time zones**:

> General time zone: Time zones are interpreted as text if they have
>   names. For time zones representing a GMT offset value, the following
>   syntax is used:
>
> ```
>  GMTOffsetTimeZone:
>          GMT Sign Hours : Minutes
>  Sign: one of          ^^^
>          + -
>  Hours:
>          Digit
>          Digit Digit
>  Minutes:
>          Digit Digit
>  Digit: one of
>          0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
> ```
>
> Hours must be between 0 and 23, and Minutes must be between 00 and 59.
>   The format is locale independent and digits must be taken from the
>   Basic Latin block of the Unicode standard.

In the definition for the general time zones, you will notice they use a ':'.

This means that your two strings, while different, will be parsed to the same time.

1. ***RFC 822*** --> 2011-07-21T19:44:00.000-0400
2. ***General*** --> 2011-07-21T19:44:00.000-04:00

Comment: I would've normally given this answer to Paul Sonier because he was first, but then MistorSquonk came along and gave a better explanation (he's also answered a good amount of questions for me and for that I thank him).  Then you come along and provide to me a complete understanding of this issue.  Thank you, sir.

Answer (score 1):

This is what Wikipedia says about ISO 8601 ['Time offsets from UTC'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC)

> The offset from UTC is given in the format ±[hh]:[mm], ±[hh][mm], or ±[hh].

So basically both formats you are using are permitted and you shouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

The colon in the second string doesn't make a difference; you can proceed without fear.